# Interaction terms and random effects in tobit regression model in R

Tags: r, regression

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to incorporate:
      a)an interaction term
      b)a random effect 
in a Tobit regression model in R?

For the interaction term I have been working on the following script, but that doesn't work.

```
fit <- vglm(GAG_p_DNA~factor(condition)+factor(time)+factor(condition):factor(time), 
      tobit(Lower = 0))
Error in if ((temp <- sum(wz[, 1:M, drop = FALSE] < wzepsilon))) warning(paste(temp,  : 
argument is not interpretable as logical
```

I have also tried this with dummy variables, created in the following way:

```
time.ch<- C(time, helmert,2)
print(attributes(time.ch))
condition.ch<-C(condition, helmert, 3)
print(attributes(condition.ch))
```

but I get the same error.

Part of the dataset (GAG_p_DNA values of zero are left censored) (Warning: to those who may be copying this. The OP used tabs as separators.)

```
Donor Time Condition GAG_p_DNA cens_GAG_p_DNA
1   1   6   0.97    1
1   1   10  0.93    1
1   7   2   16.65   1
1   7   6   0.94    1
1   7   10  1.86    1
1   28  2   21.66   1
1   28  6   0.07    1
1   28  10  3.48    1
2   1   1   1.16    1
2   1   2   2.25    1
2   1   6   2.41    1
2   1   10  1.88    1
2   7   2   13.19   1
2   7   10  2.54    1
2   28  2   23.93   1
2   28  6   0   0
2   28  10  15.17   1
```

I most likely need to use a Tobit regression model, as it seems that a Cox model with left censored data is not supported by R...

`fit<- survfit(Surv(GAG_p_DNA, cens_GAG_p_DNA, type="left")~factor(condition)+factor(Time))] [Error in coxph(Surv(GAG_p_DNA, cens_GAG_p_DNA, type = "left") ~ factor(condition) + : Cox model doesn't support "left" survival data`

Comment: I would have written it as just: `GAG_p_DNA~factor(condition)*factor(time)`

Comment: The `coxme` function in the package of the same name implements mixed effects estimation for censored data. If you offered data (possibly simulated) there might be the possibility of laying down some code.

Comment: Also, I need to use a Tobit regression model, as I have left cenosred data. With left censoring it is not possible to perform cox models in R, unfortunately.

Comment: The statement about left censoring not being possible in R is FALSE. Please read the ?Surv page in pkg:survivaL Please edit your question to include code that produces an example rather than posting poorly formatted data in comments. (There is no censoring variable in the material above.)

Comment: Still no data. Not possible to offer further advice.

Comment: Nooooooo. Please _edit_ your question,  .... and delete that useless comment with unformatted data. Prbably now would be the time to read the instructions to questioners for SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , ... , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: We are not going to be able to do very much with only one censored case but I will give it a shot. The first thing I will correct is using `0` as a censoring indicator for left censoring. The help page says to use `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
survreg(Surv( GAG_p_DNA, cens_GAG_p_DNA, type='left') ~ 
                factor(Time)*factor(Condition), data=sdat, dist='gaussian')
```

(Recommended by Therneau:  http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+therneau+left+censor+tobit#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20therneau%20left%20censor%20tobit+page:1+mid:fnczjvrnjlx5jsp5+state:results )

--- earlier effort;

With that tiny dataset (where I have corrected the use of tabs as separators) you won't get much. I corrected two errors (spelling of "Condition" and using `0` for left censoring where it should be `2` and it runs without error:

```
sdat$cens_GAG_p_DNA[sdat$cens_GAG_p_DNA==0] <- 2

fit <- survfit(Surv(GAG_p_DNA, cens_GAG_p_DNA, type="left") ~ 
                          factor(Condition) + factor(Time), data=sdat)
Warning messages:
1: In min(jtimes) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In min(jtimes) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In min(jtimes) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In min(jtimes) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In min(jtimes) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In min(jtimes) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
7: In min(jtimes) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
8: In min(jtimes) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
9: In min(jtimes) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> fit
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(GAG_p_DNA, cens_GAG_p_DNA, type = "left") ~ 
    factor(Condition) + factor(Time), data = sdat)

                                      records n.max n.start events median
factor(Condition)=1, factor(Time)=1         1     2       2      0   1.16
factor(Condition)=2, factor(Time)=1         1     2       2      0   2.25
factor(Condition)=2, factor(Time)=7         2     3       3      0  14.92
factor(Condition)=2, factor(Time)=28        2     3       3      0  22.80
factor(Condition)=6, factor(Time)=1         2     3       3      0   1.69
factor(Condition)=6, factor(Time)=7         1     2       2      0   0.94
factor(Condition)=6, factor(Time)=28        2     2       2      2   0.00
factor(Condition)=10, factor(Time)=1        2     3       3      0   1.41
factor(Condition)=10, factor(Time)=7        2     3       3      0   2.20
factor(Condition)=10, factor(Time)=28       2     3       3      0   9.32
                                      0.95LCL 0.95UCL
factor(Condition)=1, factor(Time)=1        NA      NA
factor(Condition)=2, factor(Time)=1        NA      NA
factor(Condition)=2, factor(Time)=7     13.19      NA
factor(Condition)=2, factor(Time)=28    21.66      NA
factor(Condition)=6, factor(Time)=1      0.97      NA
factor(Condition)=6, factor(Time)=7        NA      NA
factor(Condition)=6, factor(Time)=28     0.00      NA
factor(Condition)=10, factor(Time)=1     0.93      NA
factor(Condition)=10, factor(Time)=7     1.86      NA
factor(Condition)=10, factor(Time)=28    3.48      NA
```

The other aspect which I would call an error as well would be not using a `data` argument to regression functions. Trying to use "attached" dataframes, with any regression function but especially with the 'survival' package, will often cause strange errors.

I did find that putting in an interaction by way of hte formula method generated this error:

```
Error in survfit.formula(Surv(GAG_p_DNA, cens_GAG_p_DNA, type = "left") ~  : 
  Interaction terms are not valid for this function
```

And I also found that coxme::coxme, which I had speculated might give you access to mixed effects, did not handle left censoring.

```
fit <- coxme(Surv(GAG_p_DNA, cens_GAG_p_DNA, type="left")~factor(Condition)*factor(Time), data=sdat)
Error in coxme(Surv(GAG_p_DNA, cens_GAG_p_DNA, type = "left") ~ factor(Condition) *  : 
  Cox model doesn't support 'left' survival data
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the 'data' argument. Nevertheless, now you probably understand why I am interested in performing a Tobit regression and why I have asked a question about that model in the first place.